# Prevent site from deleting elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want my Chrome extension to put text on [the like button during a YouTube stream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jfKfPfyJRdk). But the `span` with the text I add is constantly deleted by the site. Is there any way to bypass this problem and prevent the site from deleting the elements created by my extension?

[image]

Comment: Maybe a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) will help.